# String Compare C# Saying "Hello World" is before "Hello"

Tags: c#, string, sorting, compare

I am trying to check if an array is well sorted but I am getting strange results.
For exemple, it says that "Hello World" or "Hello_World" must be before "Hello" which is not supposed to be the case.

Here is my code :

```
var values = match.Groups["values"].Value.Split(',');
var previousValue = string.Empty;
foreach (var value in values)
{
   var trimValue = value.Trim();
   if (trimValue.EqualsIgnoreCase("'_DefaultPartition'"))
   {
      trimValue = " ";
   }
   if (string.Compare(trimValue, previousValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) <= 0)
   {
      reason = $"{trimValue} must be before {previousValue}";
      return false;
   }
   previousValue = trimValue;
}
```

I tried CompareOptions IgnoreSymbols but it is the same issue :s

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(string.Compare("Hello World", "Hello", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase));` outputs `1` when I try it, which indicates that `"Hello World" > "Hello"`, as expected.

Comment: `Compare(a, b)` returns *negative value* if `a < b`, return `0` when `a == b` and *positive value* when `a > b`

Answer (score 0):

Let's solve the problem (find if sequence is sorted and if it is then how it is sorted) in *general case*:

```
[Flags]
public enum SortedKind {
  None = 0,
  Ascending = 1,
  Descending = 2,
  Both = Ascending | Descending, // when all items are equal to one another
}
```

Code:

```
public static SortedKind Sorted<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, IComparer<T> comparer) {
  ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
  ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(comparer);

  SortedKind result = SortedKind.Both;

  bool hasPrior = false;
  T prior = default(T);

  foreach (T item in source) {
    if (hasPrior) {
      int compare = comparer.Compare(item, prior);

      if (compare > 0)      // item > prior
        result &= SortedKind.Ascending;
      else if (compare < 0) // item < prior
        result &= SortedKind.Descending;

      if (result == SortedKind.None)
        return result;

      hasPrior = true;
      prior = item;
    }

    return result;
  }
}

public static SortedKind Sorted<T>(IEnumerable<T> source) where T : IComparable<T> =>
  Sorted(source, Comparer<T>.Default);
```

Then we can query our data and we should get that `Hello < Hello_World`

```
var values = match
  .Groups["values"]
  .Value
  .Split(',')
  .Select(item => item.EqualsIgnoreCase("'_DefaultPartition'") ? " " : item);

var result = Sorted(values, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Demo:

```
string[] items = { "Hello", "Hello World", "Hello_World" };

var result = Sorted(items, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

Console.Write(result);
```

Output:

```
Ascending
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QlpY32)

Comment: In this case "ALISE_RST" is supposed to be before "ALISECaisse" but the string comparer says the opposite :s

Comment: @Navis62: please, try `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` comparer then

Comment: Then I get the error at "'FVA_ICE' must be before 'FVA'" :s which is the first problem "Hello and Hello_World"

Comment: @Navis62: I can't reproduce `FVA_ICE < FVA`, please, fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QlpY32

Comment: @Navis62: You have `FVA'` ! `_` comes before `'` .

Comment: @Poul Bak: `'` (apostrophe) < `'A'` (and any letter). I've added some `FVA` to the fiddle.

Comment: I just copy / paste your code and I still have the error oO
I will dig this again next week

Comment: no the apostrophes were just for the exemple, they're not in the values xD

Answer (score 0):

Finally, by making this :

```
    var comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;        
    var compareOrdinal = string.Compare(value.ToString(), previousValue.ToString(), new CultureInfo("en-US"), CompareOptions.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    var compareDefault = comparer.Compare(value, previousValue);
    var compareIgnoreSymbols = string.Compare(value.ToString(), previousValue.ToString(), new CultureInfo("en-US"), CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols | CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace);
    
    switch (compareDefault > 0 || compareOrdinal > 0 || compareIgnoreSymbols > 0)
    {
        case true:
            result &= SortedKind.Ascending;
            break;
        case false:
            result &= SortedKind.Descending;
            break;
    }
```

it worked :')
it's ugly but it worked

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**